# Getting the value of input[type=hidden] in a hidden column of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have this table that has 2 columns, `personID` and `Name`. The first column is hidden. I also added a hidden input field. I did this because whenever I refresh the page, I can see its value in a split second.

I actually used datatable.  I would like to show the personID if I click on the table body. My problem is that I cannot show the personID.

```
<div class="row table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table_data"> 
    <thead class="header">
      <tr class="well">
        <th></th>
        <th>Person Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php if($result != NULL){?>
        <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
            <td> <input type="hidden" name="personID" id="personID" value="<?php  echo $row->personID;?>" />
            </td>
            <td ><?php echo $row->lname.", ".$row->fname." ".$row->mname;?></td>

        <?php }}?>

    </tbody>
  </table><!-- END Table-->
</div><!-- END table-responsive-->
```

The javascript code:

```
var table = $('#table_data').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ]

});
 $('#table_data tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var d = $('input[type=hidden]', $(this).find("td:first")).val();
         alert(d);


    }
} );
```

I have already tried the following:

I got a result undefined in here:

```
var d =  $(this).parent('td').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
var d = $('input[type=hidden]', $(this).find("td:first")).val();
```

The alert didn't show up in here:

```
var d=document.getElementById('personID').value;
```

It gives me this result , `<input name="personID" id="personID" value="19" type="hidden">`, when I tried this:

```
 var d= $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Please help me..

Comment: what should `d` be in your result?

Comment: @CodeGodie,  `d` gets the value of the first column..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little difficult to see exactly what's going wrong here. Sometimes you are referring to the hidden input having a name of "personID" in your code snippets, and sometimes "guestID". It would obviously cause issues if this disparity exists in your actual code.

If you make sure that the rendered HTML is what you expect (using personID as the hidden input's name) then the following should work:

```
$('#table_data tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    var $tr = $(this);

    if ($tr.hasClass('active')) {

        $tr.removeClass('active');

    } else {

        $tr.addClass('active');

        // Use the input's name to find it within the <tr>
        var d = $tr.find('input[name=personID]').val();

        alert(d);
    }
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codebyren/vjzy0d3x/)

Then, it seems overkill to have a whole table column just for a hidden input. You could simply place the hidden input in the same column as the person's name - or even store it as a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on the table row itself. Also, in your PHP loop, you are giving all your hidden inputs the same "personID" ID which is not technically correct - all ID values in an HTML document should be unique.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, it's actually personID...I have already edited that. And thanks for the answer, I have tried it. It works only when I didn't hide the column. But when I set `"visible"=false` , it didn't work.. I have actually tried putting it in the same column before but it didn't work due to some errors that I didn't notice. But I tried it again, and this time it worked. Thanks for the suggesting it. :)